# Cannot access git on team services release

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, devops

Im trying to execute some git commands on the Release configuration of `Team Services`.

I followed [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/git-commands#enable) guide to allow git on my Repo.
By now i can only execute this commands on the Build configuration, so i create a command line task and execute a git command there, and it works normally.

But in my Release definition, i would like to make a ´git branch´ after change the enviroment. when i try to execute a git command on my command line task e get this message: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` 
this because the Release tries to execute the command problably on my `drop` folder.

How can i execute a git command on my repo on a`Release` task.

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example of what do you want to do with git on the Release step?

Comment: I have a ´test/production´ enviroment on my release config. test is triggered when a build is succeed. For production enviroment we need to approve manually. If test is ok, we approve to production deploy. In this step of production deploy i would like to make a git tag on a speciefic branch.

Comment: I think you would need not only do `git branch` but also `git clone` or `git pull` beforehand. So that you get a repo first - and then create a branch on it. Otherwise, git can't operate on the remote repo without having it fetched in the first place.

Comment: Make sense. By the way, i have no much experience with CD enviroments. Is it usual (good practice) to make git operations on the Release configuriation? The example that i post on OP works but just on the build configuration.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong about it as long as you can see this step on your CD flow map so that it is not gets obfuscated. For example, often auto-merging techniques are used when a commit passes tests and deployment to staging. Which are in fact git operations.

Comment: Could you share the detail release long files on the OneDrive? (Set/add system.debug to true and start release, then share the log files on the loign files.

Answer (score 1):

As you realized, it’s caused the artifacts you copied to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` just part of files (such as `**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**`) not the whole source code in build definition. So there has no such a `.git` folder in `drop` folder (build artifacts).

If you need to check git repo information in release, you should specify the **contents** of **copy files** task as `**` in build. Then you can use git commands in release.

[image]

To run git commands on release, you should change the current path firstly. It is because current working directory for release like `C:\_work\r1\a`, but your git root path like `C:\_work\r1\a\buildName\drop`. So you’d better use **powershell task** to run git commands. Settings for PowerShell task:

**Type:** Inline Script
**Inline Script:**

```
cd buildName
cd drop
git branch -a
```

**Note:** Since there has no local branches for source code, you should use `git branch -a` to find all the branches in source code and current `HEAD`.

Comment: I got it to work on the aspect that now i can see my .git folder on the release drop artifact. But now im getting this error when i try to push my new branch,  `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://myteamservice.visualstudio.com': Invalid argument`. I followed this guide ( https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/git-commands ) to give permissions but this guide seems to be just for de build configuration and not for the release configuration.

Comment: It doesn't need permission since the artifacts were download locally. You can use the powershell task to execute git commands which I added details in my answer.

Comment: im running the git commands on the arctifact drop folder already, and it executes the git commands ok, the problem is when i try to push to remote.

Comment: It's caused by the `HEAD` is not point to any branches, you can create a branch (`git checkout -b temp`), and then push to remote (`git push origin temp` or `git push origin master`).

Comment: i can do all read operations, create branch and etc. but the error occours when i try to push my changes to the origin. ´fatal: could not read Username for 'https://myteamservice.visualstudio.com': Invalid argumen´

Comment: I can puh successfully by powershell task. What if you add the two commands in power shell task (to replace `git push origin <branch name> `command): `git remote add upstream <URL for VSTS git repo>` and `git push upstream <branch name>`.